# how to pass arguments to system command in perl

Tags: perl

My command:

```
system("start cmd.exe /k C:\\script.pl $arg1 $arg2 $arg3");
```

is not passing the arguments correctly. What is the correct way to do this?

Thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to invoke `system` is with an array or a list:

```
my @args = ("start", "cmd.exe", "/k", "C:\\script.pl", $arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
system @args;

system "start", "cmd.exe", "/k", "C:\\script.pl", $arg1, $arg2, $arg3;
```

Compared with a single string to `system`, this saves the complexities of 'how to quote the arguments' because the shell doesn't get a chance to interpret them.  On the other hand, if you want the shell to do I/O redirection or piping, you probably won't use this mechanism.

Comment: You don't need the array, you can just supply a list.

Comment: Agreed; you don't formally need an array variable.  See update.

Comment: using the list form of `system` will prevent perl from launching a shell in order to run `start`, but in this case `start` is then just running a `cmd.exe` shell anyway and most of the benefit is lost.  Perhaps `Win32::Console` could also be used to eliminate the `start`.

Comment: @tjd: Now you're delving into territory outside my scope — I know nothing of the Win32 packages beyond 'they exist' and 'people seriously using Windows might need to know about them'.  I currently don't use Windows at all.  That means you're probably right.