# Perl: Syntax Error; Non-Printable Chars for Key. Error Executing CMD find

Tags: perl, syntax-error, non-printable

I'm trying to pass a scalar value to the system command but keep having trouble. I'm unsure as to why. Any help would be appreciated at this late hour.

**The two errors that I'm getting are:**

> - Syntax Error; Non-Printable Chars for Key.
> - Error Executing CMD find.

Essentially what I'm trying to pass a string of commands (dbcommand; f; echo;...) within the command "command."

```
my $id_to_test = $ids[0];
my $cmd = q{command -c "dbcommand -a app-f fam -d db; f sub=a, device=};

$cmd .= q{$id_to_test};

$cmd .= q{, analog=A; echo -c on; echo -o A_value.txt; /DIS;"};

system $cmd;

#system('command-c "dbcommand-a app-f fam-d db; f sub=a, device=$id_to_test, analog=A; echo -c on; echo -o A_value.txt; /DIS;"');
```

**So now I'm doing:**

```
my $id_to_test = $ids[0];
my $cmd = 'command-c \"dbcommand-a app-f fam -d db; f sub=a, device=';
$cmd .= "$id_to_test";
$cmd .= ', analog=A; echo -c on; echo -o A_value.txt; /DIS;\"';
system $cmd;
```

and I'm getting the error:

> - Syntax error; cmd has invalid character(s) -- "dbcommand
>     sh: f: command not found
>     -c on
>     -o A_value.txt
>     sh: /DIS: No such file or directory
>     sh: ": command not found

If I do print $cmd; instead, I also get slashes in front of my double quotes, which is not what I want:

> command -c \"dbcommand -a app -f fam -d db; find sub=a, device=1234567, analog=A; echo -c on; echo -o A_value.txt; /DIS;\"

**Making sure array is populated:**

One of the first things I did was to make sure I was adding values to the array correctly by declaring the array, opening the file, and then doing:

```
while (<$fh>) {
#Remove any newline characters from line using the chomp() command.
    chomp;
    push @ids, "$_";
#   print($ids[$index]);
#   $index = $index + 1;
#   print "$row\n";
}

print join (", ", @ids);
my $array_size = @ids;
print("\n" . $array_size);
```

when I execute the perl script and it prints **locally***, everything is as expected -- values are printed and size of array is 3.

> 123456789, 123456888, 123456789
>
> 3

However, when I print ***remotely***, I only get the last element

> , 123456789
>
> 3

even though the size of the array is also 3.

Comment: Hint: read up on the difference between `q[]` and `qq[]`.

Comment: Just did, thank you for the prompt reply. The double quotes around $id_to_test are interpolating the scalar correctly, but I'm still having issues even though my print looks good.

Comment: You shouldn't be escaping the double quotes in this case.

Comment: @dimir I've tried that as well without luck unfortunately. Received the error: "Syntax error; non-printable chars for cmdline."

Comment: Try passing the parameters in a list, as also suggested in [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054068/how-to-pass-arguments-to-system-command-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you use the single quote (no interpolation) it's treating your backslash as a literal backslash.  The only time I can think of where you need a backslash as an escape character when using a single quote is when you are escaping a single quote itself or a backslash:

```
print 'I said \'hello.\'';
```

Try something like this:

```
my $cmd = 'command -c "dbcommand -a app-f fam -d db; f sub=a, device=' .
    $id_to_test . ', analog=A; echo -c on; echo -o A_value.txt; /DIS;';
```

This should also work:

```
my $cmd = 'command -c "dbcommand -a app-f fam -d db; f sub=a, device=' .
    "$id_to_test, analog=A; echo -c on; echo -o A_value.txt; /DIS;";
```

(or you could have wrapped it in one big `""` / `q{}` with no concatenation operator).

And, as others have hinted, `qq{}` is essentially "", with the added advantage that you can include double quote characters without having to escape them.

Comment: I've tried all of the above (except the list approach) and none worked. I even tried the qq() syntax and it did not help. I figured out that the variable is not being interpolated. In other words, $id_to_test isn't being converted into the value it stores (or points to). I'm wondering why that is, because isn't qq() supposed to handle the interpolation? @Hambone

Comment: My guess is that `$ids[0]` is blank.  You are correct that `qq()` will interpolate.  Can you just `print join '~', @ids` and see if it has a value for `$ids[0]`?

Comment: I did print join(", ", @ids_to_test); and  also print(@ids_to_test[0]); and both printed the expected values. I'm not sure what else I can do. @Hambone

Comment: This may be overstating the obvious, but if you `print $cmd` does it list the correct ID or is it blank?

Comment: I'm testing this program locally as well as remotely. I guess I was confused and thought the array of IDs (ids_to_test) was being populated both locally and remotely, but it is being populate only locally. When I run the same program remotely, the array is not populated. Which is strange to me to say the least. Moreover, when I do print($cmd) locally the output is fine, remotely however, it's not. I suppose both problems are related. @Hambone